# How do I make items disappear based on the size of it's members?

Tags: design, algorithms, asynchronous-programming

Consider a list of items (take a list of voice channels) where each item has these attributes

[image: UML Diagram]

`System::vc`: List of voice channels.

`System::on_join(member, before, after)`: On the event when a member joins a `VoiceChannel` the first time, it's `before` is `Null` and  `after` is a `VoiceChannel`. When a member switches voice channels, `before` and `after` are different `VoiceChannels`.

`System::on_leave(member, before, after)`: On the event when a member leaves all voice channels (ie: does not switch to another `VoiceChannel`), before will be a `VoiceChannel` and after will be `Null`.

`System::get_room(no)`: Get a `VoiceChannel` from it's number.

`VoiceChannel::number`: The  number of the `VoiceChannel` (ie, index of `System::vc` + 1).

`VoiceChannel::is_empty()`: Returns `True` if there are no members in the channel, else `False`.

`VoiceChannel::is_visible()`: Returns `True` if the channel is currently visible, else `False`.

`VoiceChannel::make_visible()`: Makes a channel visible to all members. Returns `True` if successful and `False` if not.

`VoiceChannel::make_invisible()`: Makes a channel invisible to all members. Returns `True` if successful and `False` if not.

---

I'm trying to develop an algorithm to obtain this result when applied on `System::vc`:

1. When a member joins a `VoiceChannel` it should make the first invisible and  empty channel in the list visible.
2. If one empty`VoiceChannel` is already visible then don't make any new ones visible.
3. If more than one empty channel is visible then only make the first empty channel visible.

### Notes

1. All `VoiceChannel` items except the first are invisible in initial state.
2. A member can only join one `VoiceChannel` at a time.
3. A member needs to join at least one `VoiceChannel` before they can switch between voice channels. So it's not possible to switch from channel 1 to channel 2 without having first already joined channel 1.

## What I have tried

### Psuedocode

```py
def on_join(member, before, after):
    vc_visible = []
    for vc in self.vc:  # self is an instance of System
        if is_visible(vc):
            vc_visible.append(vc)
    
    last_vc_number = len(vc_visible) + 1
    if last_vc_number == 21:  # Total number of VoiceChannels + 1
        return
    
    self.vc_last = self.get_room(last_vc_number)
    for vc in self.vc:
        if is_visible(vc) and is_empty(vc) and vc.number != 1:
            self.vc_next_visible = vc
            return
        elif vc == self.vc_next_visible:
            await make_visible(self.vc_next_visible)
            return
        else:
            await make_visible(self.vc_last)
            return

async def on_leave(member, before, after):
    vc_visible = []
    for vc in self.vc:  # self is an instance of System
        if is_visible(vc):
            vc_visible.append(vc)

    # Cycle through list from second last to front
    for vc in vc_visible[:len(vc_visible) * -1 :-1]:
        if is_empty(vc) and is_empty(vc_visible[0]):
            await make_invisible(vc)
        elif is_empty(vc):
            if vc != self.vc_next_visible and vc.number != 2:
                await make_invisible(vc)

    for vc in self.vc:
        if is_visible(vc) and is_empty(vc) and vc.number != 1:
            self.vc_next_visible = vc
            return
```

## Question

How do I go about writing psuedo code or a concrete algorithm to make this work with just `on_join` and `on_leave` events?

Comment: "When a member joins a VoiceChannel it should make the next one in the list visible."  to whom?  Everyone or just that member?

Comment: @ErikEidt To everyone. The `make_visible` and `make_invisible` methods make the channels visible and invisible to everyone. The details of how the function works is not important, just know that it automatically does it for all members.

Comment: "On the event when a member leaves all voice channels (ie: does not switch to another VoiceChannel), before will be a VoiceChannel and after will be Null."  Why do you need to pass one VoiceChannel if they are leaving all of them?  Which one is passed?

Comment: What would `on_leave` mean if you passed two voice channels instead of one and NULL (which means leave all)?

Comment: Maintain a list of "currently invisible" channels in sorted order. Whenever there's need to convert a currently invisible channel into a visible one, pick from the top of this list. When a channel turns into invisible, put that channel into the list, and sort it.

Comment: It is slightly similar to the object pool pattern (despite having different motivations), where items that are currently unused are maintained in a collection (data structure). While items inside an object pool are interchangeable and therefore unsorted, a similar pattern exists for "unused table rows pattern" (table also means data grid) in which unused table rows return to action in an orderly fashion, starting with unused rows closest to the top of the table.

Comment: @daegontaven again nice edit. I still have some questions. Is point 1 only meant to be true at the start? Otherwise it contradicts 2. 3 and 4 seem to have the goal of maintaining exactly one visible empty channel. Is there ever the case where there are no visible empty channels? If any of these points are only true sometimes I'd like to know what those times are.

Comment: @candied_orange The numbers have changed, so I am assuming you are referring to the point 1 in notes. Then yes, it's meant to be true only at the start. If you are referencing point 1 of the algorithm, then no it's meant to be true on all joins. In addition there is never a case where there are no empty visible channels. If that were true then no one would be able to join a channel because they are invisible. For instance, when no one has joined a channel, channel 1 is always visible. When channel 1 is occupied by at least one person, channel 2 is visible for someone to join.

Comment: Point 1 = "When a member joins ..."

Comment: @candied_orange When channel 1 and 2 are occupied, channel 3 is visible for someone to join. If channel 1 becomes empty while 2 and 3 are occupied, then channel 4 won't become visible because channel 1 is empty.

Comment: @candied_orange I've reworded point 1 again. Please take a look. Per the reworded point 1, I assume it has to be true on all joins for the scenario in my previous comment to work.

Comment: Notes 2 and 3 make perfect sense to me. Note 1 leaves me confused. "All VoiceChannel items except the first are invisible in initial state." What are VoiceChannel Items? Are they different than channels? What is "initial state"? How do we get into a different state?

Comment: The initial state of the whole layout is just what the state of each voice channel is before the application triggers any events. To get to a different state of layout, a VoiceChannel must be made invisible. In essence if anything changes in the system, it's a different state. VoiceChannel items are not different from channels in this context. Here is a gallery of images to better visualize this process https://imgur.com/a/PYHdhiy.

Comment: @candied_orange Another way of looking at the initial state is that when the program first executes, if we were to query all voice channels with `is_visible()`, only the first one would be visible.

Comment: @daegontaven so all 1 is saying is that the system starts with one visible  channel, which is empty.

Comment: @candied_orange Yes :)

Comment: It sounds like you're doing something similar to an object pool. Would it make sense to add a class to manage the entire set of available `VoiceChannel`, rather than `System` operating on a list directly?

Comment: This looks like something where TDD could be really helpful - instead of trying to come up with pseudocode, write real code that you can immediately run and get immediate feedback on if its working or not, and you can debug it. Perfect way to develop your intuition on how to go about the problem, and to catch your mistakes and misconceptions early.

Comment: Could this be summarized like this: (1) there's always exactly one empty channel visible, (2) users can join or leave visible channels [a channel is empty if there are no users], (3) if a user joins the (single visible) empty channel, make the first available empty channel visible [to maintain (1)], (4) if a user leaving results in an extra empty channel, only show the first empty channel [again, to maintain (1)]?

Comment: Also, is this all processed sequentially (e.g., in an event loop), or is there some form of parallelism involved?

Comment: @FilipMilovanović I actually tested this code on real world code multiple times, but I still couldn't figure it out. Anyways your summary sounds exactly correct, I just don't know how to convert it into an algorithm. All of this is processed sequentially in an event loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop asking things about their state and start telling them what you want.  Also, don't use null if you can help it.

With that in mind here's a redesign:

`System::on_join(member, after, emptyChannel)` On the event when a member joins a VoiceChannel the first time, after is the VoiceChannel they join.

`System::on_switch(member, before, after, emptyChannel)` When a member switches voice channels, before and after are different VoiceChannels.

`System::on_leave(member, before, after, emptyChannel)` On the event when a member leaves all voice channels (ie: does not switch to another VoiceChannel), before will be a VoiceChannel and after will be Null.

Both on_switch and on_leave can call `leaveChannel(member, before, emptyChannel)` and tell the channel about the member leaving. The channel can update it's member list, update it's visibility, or file a tax return, whatever the channel wants to do.

Both on_switch and on_join can call `joinChannel(member, after, emptyChannel)` and tell the channel about the member leaving. The channel can update it's member list, update it's visibility, or send the member spam email, whatever the channel wants to do.

This might seem weird but you can make the channels smart enough to handle this stuff on their own. All they need to know is that it's time to check if they should be visible, how many members they have, and if empty, if `emptyChannel` is lower numbered or conversely if it just got filled. With that info they can figure out visibility themselves. You don't have to keep building lists.

Comment: Can you explain what is `emptyChannel`? I'm still not following your algorithm.

Comment: nvm i figured it out

Comment: Rather than `before` and `after` consider the names `leaving` and `joining`.